# In Discord How to get new channel detail right away once added by anyone

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to set up an automatic monitoring system where it keeps on monitoring if anybody has added any new channel under a particular category like "Games" then I should get new channel name and ID right away. I am trying to achieve this for only those server which I have joined.

I tried couple of solutions even tried using websockets but success. I tried with Bot as well but it doesn't trigger the channel creation event.

```
import discord

TOKEN = 'MTEV_w'


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user.name} ({client.user.id})')
```

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!get_channels'):
        category_name = 'Games'
        guild = discord.utils.get(client.guilds, id='101780234')

        if guild:
            category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name=category_name)
            if category:
                public_channels = [channel.name for channel in category.channels if not channel.private]
                await message.channel.send(f'Public channels in category "{category_name}": {", ".join(public_channels)}')
            else:
                await message.channel.send(f'Category "{category_name}" not found.')
        else:
            await message.channel.send('Server not found.')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Can anybody help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the `on_message` event, use [`on_guild_channel_create`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_guild#discord.on_guild_channel_create):

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
    if channel.guild.id != 101780234:  # your guild ID (as an integer...)
        return

    if channel.category.name.lower() != "games":
        return

    channel_id = channel.id
    channel_name = channel.name

    # do something with those variables...
```